# Why won't my WP widget respond to my code edits? TPL is involved

Tags: php, wordpress

*(Posted this on the WP StackExchange, but was sent back here. So hello!)*

I'm attempting to modify a WP widget that displays the portfolio page from this template, [Royal Startex](http://themeforest.net/item/royalstartex-minimalist-business-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/5298957) (please click **Portfolio** in the header). The template is based on the [Klasik Framework](http://www.klasikthemes.com/framework/). Documentation for both is nearly non-existent.

As it stands, the widget pulls category-based posts & their post thumbnail and displays them as a grid; clicking on the image effects a lightbox & slideshow effect.

Instead, I'd like clicking on the image to go directly to the post. No lightbox, no slideshow. I've been attempting to modify the plugin's code, but haven't had any luck. My changes don't seem to have any effect (unless I just delete a bunch of random code, which breaks the page). **I'm assuming the main problem is my unfamiliarity with how $tpl works**. First time I've seen it.

Here's the plugin code:

```
        function Klasik_PFilterWidget() {
            $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget_klasik_pfilter', 'description' => __('KlasikThemes Portfolio Filter','klasik') );
            $this->WP_Widget('klasik-theme-pfilter-widget', __('KlasikThemes Portfolio Filter','klasik'), $widget_ops);
        }


      /** @see WP_Widget::widget */
        function widget($args, $instance) {     
            extract( $args );
            $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? '' : $instance['title']);
            $cats = apply_filters('widget_category', empty($instance['category']) ? array() : $instance['category']);
            $display = apply_filters('widget_display', empty($instance['display']) ? '' : $instance['display']);
            $cols = apply_filters('widget_cols', empty($instance['cols']) ? '' : $instance['cols']);
            $showposts = apply_filters('widget_showpost', empty($instance['showpost']) ? '' : $instance['showpost']);
            $longdesc = apply_filters('widget_longdesc', empty($instance['longdesc']) ? '' : $instance['longdesc']);
            $customclass = apply_filters('widget_customclass', empty($instance['customclass']) ? '' : $instance['customclass']);
            $enablepagenum = apply_filters('widget_enablepagenum', isset($instance['enablepagenum']));
            $instance['category'] = isset($instance['category'])? $instance['category'] : "";
            global $wp_query;
            ?>
                  <?php echo $before_widget; 
                        if ( $title!='' )
                            echo $before_title . esc_html($title) . $after_title;

                        $cols = intval($cols);

                        if(!is_numeric($cols) || $cols < 1 || $cols > 6){
                            $cols = 4;
                        }

                        $longdesc = (!is_numeric($longdesc) || empty($longdesc))? 0 : $longdesc;

                        $showposts = (!is_numeric($showposts))? get_option('posts_per_page') : $showposts;
                        $categories = $cats;

                        echo '<div class="klasik-portfolio '.$customclass.'">';

                            $approvedcat = array();
                            $sideoutput = "";
                            if( count($categories)!=0 ){
                                foreach ($categories as $key) {
                                    $catname = get_term_by("slug",$key,"category");
                                    $approvedcat[] = $key;
                                }
                            }

                            $approvedcatID = array();
                            $isotopeclass = "";
                            if( $display == 'filterable'){
                                echo '<div class="frame-filter">';
                                    echo '<div class="filterlist">';
                                        echo '<ul id="filter" class="controlnav">';
                                            echo '<li class="segment-1 selected-1 current first"><a href="#" data-filter="*">'.__('All Categories','klasik').'</a></li>';
                                            foreach ($categories as $key) {
                                                $catname = get_term_by("slug",$key,"category");
                                                echo '<li class="segment-1"><a href="#" class="'.$catname->slug.'" data-filter="'.$catname->slug.'">'.$catname->name.'</a></li>';
                                                $approvedcatID[] = $key;
                                            }
                                        echo '</ul>';
                                    echo '</div>';
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
                                $isotopeclass = "isotope portfoliolist";
                                $showposts = -1;
                            }else{
                                foreach ($categories as $key) {
                                    $catname = get_term_by("slug",$key,"category");
                                    $approvedcatID[] = $key;
                                }
                            }

                            if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
                            elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
                            else { $paged = 1; }

                            $temp = $wp_query;
                            $wp_query= null;
                            $wp_query = new WP_Query();

                            $args = array(
                                'post_type'         => 'post',
                                "paged"             => $paged,
                                'showposts'         => $showposts,
                                'orderby'           => 'date'
                            );

                            if( count($approvedcatID) ){
                                $args['tax_query'] = array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $approvedcat
                                    )
                                );
                            }

                            $wp_query->query($args);
                            global $post;

                            $tpl  = '<div data-id="id-%%ID%%" class="%%CLASS%%" data-type="%%KEY%%">';

                                $tpl .= '<div class="klasik-pf-img"><div class="shadowBottom">';
                                    $tpl .= '<a class="pfzoom" href="%%FULLIMG%%" %%LBOXREL%% title="%%TITLE%%"><span class="rollover"></span>%%THUMB%%</a>';
                                    $tpl .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
                                $tpl .= '</div></div>';

                                $tpl .= '<div class="klasik-pf-text">';
                                    $tpl .='<h3 class="pftitle"><a href="%%LINK%%" title="%%TITLE%%">';
                                        $tpl .='<span>%%TITLE%%</span>';
                                    $tpl .='</a></h3>';
                                    $tpl .='<div class="textcontainer">%%TEXT%%</div>';
                                $tpl .= '</div>';

                                $tpl .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
                            $tpl .= '</div>';
                            $tpl = apply_filters( 'klasik_pfilter_item_template', $tpl );

                            if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : 
                                $x = 0;
                                $output = "";
                                $output .= '<div class="row '.$isotopeclass.'">';
                                while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 

                                    $template = $tpl;

                                    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                                    $cf_price = (isset($custom['custom-price'][0]))? $custom['custom-price'][0] : "";
                                    $cf_customdesc      = get_the_title() ;

                                    $x++;

                                    if($cols==1){
                                        $colclass = "twelve columns";
                                    }elseif($cols==2){
                                        $colclass = "one_half columns";
                                    }elseif($cols==3){
                                        $colclass = "one_third columns";
                                    }elseif($cols==4){  
                                        $colclass = "one_fourth columns";
                                    }elseif($cols==5){
                                        $colclass = "one_fifth columns";
                                    }elseif($cols==6){
                                        $colclass = "one_sixth columns";
                                    }


                                    if($x%$cols==0){
                                        $omega = "omega";
                                    }elseif($x%$cols==1){
                                        $omega = "alpha";
                                    }else{
                                        $omega = "";
                                    }               

                                    $itemclass = $colclass .' '. $omega;

                                    //get post-thumbnail attachment
                                    $attachments = get_children( array(
                                        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                                        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                                        'post_mime_type' => 'image')
                                    );

                                    $fullimageurl = '';
                                    $cf_thumb2 = '';


                                    foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment ) {
                                        $getimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att_id, 'widget-portfolio', true);
                                        $fullimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att_id, 'full', true);
                                        $portfolioimage = $getimage[0];
                                        $cf_thumb2 ='<img src="'.$portfolioimage.'" alt="" />';
                                        $thethumblb = $portfolioimage;
                                        $fullimageurl = $fullimage[0];
                                    }

                                    //thumb image
                                    if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){
                                        $cf_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'widget-portfolio');
                                        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
                                        $args = array(
                                            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                                            'post_status' => null,
                                            'include' => $thumb_id
                                        );
                                        $fullimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'full', true);
                                        $fullimageurl = $fullimage[0];

                                        $thumbnail_image = get_posts($args);
                                        if ($thumbnail_image && isset($thumbnail_image[0])) {
                                            $cf_customdesc = $thumbnail_image[0]->post_content;
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        $cf_thumb = $cf_thumb2;
                                    }

                                    //LIGHTBOX URL 
                                    //$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                                    //$cf_lightboxurl = (isset($custom["lightbox-url"][0]) && $custom["lightbox-url"][0]!="")? $custom["lightbox-url"][0] : "";

                                    //if($cf_lightboxurl != ""){
                                    //  $fullimageurl = $cf_lightboxurl;
                                    //}

                                    $format = get_post_format($post->ID);

                                    if(($format=="video")||($format=="audio")){
                                        $lightboxrel = "";
                                        $fullimageurl = get_permalink();
                                    }else{
                                        $lightboxrel = "data-rel=prettyPhoto[mixed]";
                                    }


                                    $ids = get_the_ID();

                                    $addclass="";

                                    $catinfos = get_the_terms($post->ID,'category');
                                    $key = "";
                                    if($catinfos){
                                        foreach($catinfos as $catinfo){
                                            $key .= " ".$catinfo->slug;
                                        }
                                        $key = trim($key);
                                    }

                                    //PORTFOLIOID
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%ID%%', $post->ID, $template );

                                    //POST-DAY
                                    $postday  = '';
                                    $postday .= get_the_time( 'd' );
                                    $template   = str_replace( '%%DAY%%', $postday, $template );

                                    //POST-MONTH
                                    $postmonth  = '';
                                    $postmonth .= get_the_time('M');
                                    $template   = str_replace( '%%MONTH%', $postmonth, $template );

                                    //POST-YEAR
                                    $postyear  = '';
                                    $postyear .= get_the_time('Y');
                                    $template   = str_replace( '%%YEAR%', $postyear, $template );


                                    //PORTFOLIOCLASS
                                    $pfclass  = 'item ';
                                    $pfclass .= $itemclass.' ';
                                    $pfclass .= $key;
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%CLASS%%', $pfclass, $template );

                                    //PORTFOLIOKEY
                                    $pfkey = $key;
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%KEY%%', $pfkey, $template );

                                    //PORTFOLIOFULLIMAGE
                                    $pffullimg = $fullimageurl;
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%FULLIMG%%', $pffullimg, $template );

                                    //LIGHTBOXREL
                                    $pflightbox = $lightboxrel;
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%LBOXREL%%', $pflightbox, $template );

                                    //PORTFOLIOIMGTITLE
                                    $pffullimgtitle = $cf_customdesc;
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%FULLIMGTITLE%%', $pffullimgtitle, $template );

                                    //PORTFOLIOLINK
                                    $pflink = get_permalink();
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%LINK%%', $pflink, $template );

                                    //PORTFOLIOIMAGE
                                    $pfthumb = '';
                                    $pfthumb .= $cf_thumb;
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%THUMB%%', $pfthumb, $template );

                                    //PRICE
                                    $pfprice = '';
                                    $pfprice .= $cf_price;
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%PRICE%%', $pfprice, $template );

                                    //TAGS
                                    $pftags = "";
                                    $posttags = get_the_tags();
                                    $count=0;
                                    if ($posttags) {
                                      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                                        $count++;
                                        if (1 == $count) {
                                          $pftags .= $tag->name . ' ';
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%TAG%%', $pftags, $template );


                                    //PORTFOLIOTITLE
                                    $pftitle  = '';
                                    $pftitle .= get_the_title();
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%TITLE%%', $pftitle, $template );

                                    //PORTFOLIOTEXT
                                    $pftext = '';
                                    if($longdesc>0){
                                        $excerpt = klasik_string_limit_char(get_the_excerpt(), $longdesc);
                                    }else{
                                        $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                                    }
                                    $pftext .= $excerpt;
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%TEXT%%', $pftext, $template );

                                    //PORTFOLIOCATEGORY
                                    $pfcat = '';
                                    $categories = get_the_category();
                                    $separator = ', ';
                                    if($categories){
                                        foreach($categories as $category) {
                                            $pfcat .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", 'klasik' ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $template = str_replace( '%%CATEGORY%%', trim($pfcat, $separator), $template );

                                $output .= $template;
                                endwhile;

                                $output .= '</div>';

                                if($enablepagenum){
                                    ob_start();
                                    klasik_pagination();
                                    $output.='<div class="clear"></div>';
                                    $output .= ob_get_contents();
                                    $output.='<div class="clear"></div>';
                                    ob_end_clean();
                                }


                                echo $output;
                            endif;
                            $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; wp_reset_query();
                            echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    ?>

                  <?php echo $after_widget; ?>

            <?php
        }

        /** @see WP_Widget::update */
        function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {             

            return $new_instance;
        }

        /** @see WP_Widget::form */
        function form($instance) {
            $instance['title'] = (isset($instance['title']))? $instance['title'] : "";
            $instance['category'] = (isset($instance['category']))? $instance['category'] : array();
            $instance['display'] = (isset($instance['display']))? $instance['display'] : "";
            $instance['cols'] = (isset($instance['cols']))? $instance['cols'] : "";
            $instance['showpost'] = (isset($instance['showpost']))? $instance['showpost'] : "";
            $instance['longdesc'] = (isset($instance['longdesc']))? $instance['longdesc'] : "";
            $instance['customclass'] = (isset($instance['customclass']))? $instance['customclass'] : "";
            $instance['enablepagenum'] = (isset($instance['enablepagenum']))? $instance['enablepagenum'] : "";

            $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
            $categories = $instance['category'];
            $display = esc_attr($instance['display']);
            $cols = esc_attr($instance['cols']);
            $showpost = esc_attr($instance['showpost']);
            $customclass = esc_attr($instance['customclass']);
            $longdesc = esc_attr($instance['longdesc']);
            $enablepagenum = esc_attr($instance['enablepagenum']);


            ?>
                <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'klasik'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></label></p>

                <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>"><?php _e('Category:', 'klasik'); ?><br />
                <?php 
                $chkvalue = $categories;

                $portcategories = get_categories();
                $returnstring = '';
                foreach($portcategories as $category){
                    $checkedstr="";
                    if(in_array($category->slug,$chkvalue)){
                        $checkedstr = 'checked="checked"';
                    }
                    $returnstring .= '<div style="float:left;width:48%;">';
                    $returnstring .= '<label for="'. $this->get_field_id('category')."-". $category->slug .'">';
                        $returnstring .= '<input type="checkbox" value="'. $category->slug .'" name="'. $this->get_field_name('category'). '['.$category->slug.']" id="'. $this->get_field_id('category')."-". $category->slug . '" '.$checkedstr.' />&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $category->name;
                    $returnstring .= '</label>';
                    $returnstring .= '</div>';
                }
                $returnstring .= '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';

                echo $returnstring;
                ?>
                </label></p>
                <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('display'); ?>"><?php _e('Display:', 'klasik'); ?></label><br />
                <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('display'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('display'); ?>" class="widefat" style="width:50%;">
                    <?php foreach($this->get_display_options() as $k => $v ) { ?>
                        <option <?php selected( $instance['display'], $k); ?> value="<?php echo $k; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>      
                </select></p>

                <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cols'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of Columns:', 'klasik'); ?></label><br />
                <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cols'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('cols'); ?>" class="widefat" style="width:50%;">
                    <?php foreach($this->get_number_options() as $k => $v ) { ?>
                        <option <?php selected( $instance['cols'], $k); ?> value="<?php echo $k; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>      
                </select></p>

                <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('showpost'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of Post:', 'klasik'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('showpost'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('showpost'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $showpost; ?>" /></label></p>

                <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('longdesc'); ?>"><?php _e('Length of Description Text:', 'klasik'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('longdesc'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('longdesc'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $longdesc; ?>" /></label></p>

                <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('customclass'); ?>"><?php _e('Custom Class:', 'klasik'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('customclass'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('customclass'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $customclass; ?>" /></label></p>

                <p>
                <?php if($instance['enablepagenum']){ $checked = "checked=\"checked\""; }else{ $checked = ""; } ?>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('enablepagenum'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('enablepagenum'); ?>" value="true" <?php echo $checked; ?> />            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('enablepagenum'); ?>"><?php _e('Enable Paging', 'klasik'); ?> </label></p>

            <?php
        }
        protected function get_display_options () {
            return array(
                        'default'           => __( 'Default', 'klasik' ),       
                        'filterable'        => __( 'Filterable', 'klasik' )
                        );
        } // End get_display_options()

        protected function get_number_options () {
            return array(
                        '1'             => __( '1 Column', 'klasik' ),      
                        '2'             => __( '2 Column', 'klasik' ),
                        '3'             => __( '3 Column', 'klasik' ),
                        '4'             => __( '4 Column', 'klasik' ),
                        '5'             => __( '5 Column', 'klasik' ),
                        '6'             => __( '6 Column', 'klasik' )
                        );
        } // End get_number_options()


    } // class  Widget
```

The relevant code, to me, appears to be this:

```
    $tpl  = '<div data-id="id-%%ID%%" class="%%CLASS%%" data-type="%%KEY%%">';

    $tpl .= '<div class="klasik-pf-img"><div class="shadowBottom">';
    $tpl .= '<a class="pfzoom" href="%%FULLIMG%%" %%LBOXREL%% title="%%TITLE%%"><span class="rollover"></span>%%THUMB%%</a>';
    $tpl .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
    $tpl .= '</div></div>';

    $tpl .= '<div class="klasik-pf-text">';
    $tpl .='<h3 class="pftitle"><a href="%%LINK%%" title="%%TITLE%%">';
    $tpl .='<span>%%TITLE%%</span>';
    $tpl .='</a></h3>';
    $tpl .='<div class="textcontainer">%%TEXT%%</div>';
    $tpl .= '</div>';

    $tpl .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
    $tpl .= '</div>';
    $tpl = apply_filters( 'klasik_pfilter_item_template', $tpl );
```

My semi-educated guess was this, to wrap the whole thing in an  code. No dice.

```
    $tpl  = '<div data-id="id-%%ID%%" class="%%CLASS%%" data-type="%%KEY%%">';

    $tpl .='<a href="%%LINK%%" title="%%TITLE%%">'; <!-- MOVE THIS UP -->

    $tpl .= '<div class="klasik-pf-img"><div class="shadowBottom">';
    $tpl .= '<a class="pfzoom" href="%%FULLIMG%%" %%LBOXREL%% title="%%TITLE%%"><span class="rollover"></span>%%THUMB%%</a>';
    $tpl .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
    $tpl .= '</div></div>';

    $tpl .= '<div class="klasik-pf-text">';
    $tpl .='<a href="%%LINK%%" title="%%TITLE%%">';
    $tpl .='<span>%%TITLE%%</span>';

    $tpl .='<div class="textcontainer">%%TEXT%%</div>';
    $tpl .= '</div>';

    $tpl .='</a>';   <!-- AND MOVE THIS DOWN -->

    $tpl .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
    $tpl .= '</div>';
    $tpl = apply_filters( 'klasik_pfilter_item_template', $tpl );
```

I at least thought that'd be a good starting point, but nope. Nothing. Am I editing the wrong code?

Help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Task Parallel Library is not the TPL you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to do here which I figured out by looking at the javascript console of the demo site (http://demowordpress.templatesquare.com/royalstartex/portfolio/).  Note that you won't see the same info if you click on the link that you provided until you click 'Remove Frame' to get rid of the outer frame.

First off $tpl is nothing more than a php variable.  It could be called $dingleberry if you want.  So $tpl is not a thing that you need to understand.  This is just basic PHP.

The link to the page seems to come from %%LINK%%.  So put that link in the href for the image, and get rid of the text section.  There's probably more you could clean up:

```
$tpl  = '<div data-id="id-%%ID%%" class="%%CLASS%%" data-type="%%KEY%%">';

$tpl .= '<div class="klasik-pf-img"><div class="shadowBottom">';

// Note that I changed the href below

$tpl .= '<a class="pfzoom" href="%%LINK%%" %%LBOXREL%% title="%%TITLE%%"><span class="rollover"></span>%%THUMB%%</a>';
$tpl .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
$tpl .= '</div></div>';

$tpl .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
$tpl .= '</div>';
$tpl = apply_filters( 'klasik_pfilter_item_template', $tpl );
```

Second is the lightbox.  You can first try removing the pfzoom class from the a tag but that might mess up some styling.
    $tpl .= '

An easier way to disable the lightbox is to disable the click events that have been bound to the a tag.  Add this to your jQuery block somewhere.  Or here's a complete jQuery block that you could just use anywhere:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // disable every handler bound to the .pfzoom class and just do a normal anchor tag click
  $('.pfzoom').off();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @manishie! This looks spot on — and I appreciate the $tpl clarification. However, I've pasted this code into the PHP file in place of the original text, and I'm not seeing any changes on my page. Is there another file I should be modifying, other than the one above?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea.  I've never used this theme.  One that I do often when trying to figure out which template file a page is using is to type in some text at the top of the template file (e.g. XXXXXXX), save, then see if those changes appear on my page.  if so, you know you have the right file.  if not, time to look for another file.

Comment: also, you shouldn't be editing the theme files directly.  if the theme file ever gets updated (quite easy to accidentally do in the wp admin interface) your changes will be overwritten.  please use a child theme instead: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes.